# html auto play audio not working for some reason

Tags: html, audio

here is my code

```
<video loop="true" width = "700px" autoplay muted>
  <source src="test5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video loop="true" width = "780px" autoplay muted>
  <source src="video-copy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<audio autoplay> 
    <source src="video-copy.mp3" />
</audio>
<audio autoplay> 
    <source src="test5.mp3" />
</audio>
```

for some reason the audio only plays half of the time ive tried on google chrome and opera but both same results could anyone tell me why

Comment: Does [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_autoplay), work for you?

Answer (score 0):

First off, where do you need this code to work ? Is it on a local HTML or PHP file, or on a live website ?

If you want to implement this code on a live website, do you have an SSL contract linked to your domain name (meaning is the URL starting with https:// and not http://)

I read that for security reasons, most browsers block the autoplay of audios and videos if the website is not running with a SSL contract (because the website is not secured).

Comment: yes it does have a ssl contract the site im using is run off 000webhost

Comment: it seems if i put the website in a shortened link the audio works fine

Comment: Alright, can I have a link to the concerned pages ?